# Update backbone model on change of global variable?

Tags: backbone.js, geolocation, backbone-events

I have a Collection of Venue objects which all have their own lat/long properties, using this and the users position I can calculate the distance between user and each venue.

My issue is that I can't only do this when the Venue objects are created so need to trigger this calculation when the position variable is updated, either by watching the position variable or by triggering a function, I'm not having much success with either method.

```
window.App = {};

// Venue Object
App.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/rest/venue',
  defaults: {
    distance: ''
  },
  initialize: function(){
    console.log(App.position);
    this.set('distance', getDistance(App.position.coords.latitude, App.position.coords.longitude, this.get('latitude'), this.get('longitude')));
  },
  events: {
    // Doesn't seem to work
    App.position.on('change', function() { console.log('change event'); })
  },
  updateDistance: function() {
    console.log('updateDistance');
  }
});

// Venues Collection Object
App.Venues = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/venues',
  model: App.Venue,
  comparator: function(venue) {
    return venue.get('name');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  // Setup Model
  App.venues = new App.Venues();

  App.venues.fetch();

  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(gotPosition);

  function gotPosition(position) {
    console.log(position);
    App.position = position;
    // Somehow trigger updateDistance function on all model objects?
  }
});
```

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of dealing with this.

#### Position is a Backbone.Model

If your position is a backbone model as opposed to a simple variable then you could do something like:

```
// Give the position to each venue    
App.venues = new App.Venues({position: position}); //doesn't matter if the position variable is just empty right now.
```

in your App.Venue model initialize method:

```
App.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
initialize: function(options) {
   this.position = options.position //save the reference
   this.listenTo(this.position, "change", positionChanged) //now your venue model is watching this position object. any change and positionChanged method will be called
},

positionChanged: function (model) {
// position updated

}
```

#### Global Event Aggregator

So incase for some reason you don't have position as Backbone model, then you could setup your own event aggregator by extending Backbone.Events module:

```
App.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Whenever position is updated, you trigger an event:

```
function gotPosition(position) {
    console.log(position);
    App.position = position;
    App.vent.trigger("position:updated") // you could name this event anything.
 }
```

In your Venue model you listen to the events:

```
App.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function(options) {
        App.vent.on("position:updated", this.positionChanged)
    },
```

I would prefer the first method !